# How to view my sent tweets?

Tags: twitter

Why can't I see my tweets? My profile says I sent 46 (and I did), but when I click on Tweets, I cannot see them and Twitter says:

> Send your first Tweet!

Why is that?

(one of my tweets is from yesterday, so not the issue you refer to about old tweets)

Comment: The answer on the linked duplicate is not great, so if you are looking for a better answer, please add a bounty (once you have at least 75 reputation) or otherwise to get more attention on it.

Answer (score -1):

Your 46 Tweets should be visible on your profile page: **`https://twitter.com/YOURUSERNAME`** or try: **https://www.allmytweets.net/connect/**

You can also try to download your Twitter archive which allows you to browse a snapshot of your Twitter information, starting with your first Tweet. To download and view your Twitter archive:

> [image]
>
> **https://help.twitter.com/en/search?q=archive**

Other option would be to paste this string into Twitter's search box:

**`from:YOURUSERNAME since:2007-01-01 until:2019-01-19`**

- **note:** click **All** to see every tweet from this time period

...or use Twiter's advanced search:

> [image: 5]
>
> **https://twitter.com/search-advanced?lang=en**

Comment: Precisely, when I go to https://twitter.com/YOURUSERNAME, I see a blank page saying Send your first Tweet. I can try the alternative method, but this won't let me delete a tweet I want to delete

Comment: I just requested my archive and i get a blank file. However my profile says I have 46 tweets

Comment: is it because it says my tweets are protected ?

Comment: i am on desktop

Comment: yes of course i changed to my username

Comment: yes i do see them under there, but cannot delete one, which is what i want

Comment: doing the search, i find my profile, not my tweets

Comment: well, i used one of these apps to delete the tweet i wanted, but I do not understand why I have never been able to see my tweets

Comment: is there a way i can sort of reset my account to fix this problem ? I have NEVER been able to view my own tweets

Comment: you will need to contact tech support: https://help.twitter.com/en/contact-us